# Error from server: User "system" cannot create imagestreams in project "openshift"

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm quite new with openshift.org. I tried to build a cluster, with 3 masters (including etcd), 1 lb and 2 nodes.

I'm building that from ansible as described in https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#multiple-masters

Ansible works great until:

> TASK: [openshift_examples | Import Centos Image streams]
>   failed: [...] => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["oc", "create", "-n", "openshift", "-f", "/usr/share/openshift/examples/image-streams/image-streams-centos7.json"], "delta": "0:00:00.290493", "end": "2016-01-25 18:30:04.688765", "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-01-25 18:30:04.398272", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
>   stderr: Error from server: User "system" cannot create imagestreams in project "openshift"
>   [...]

Looks like etcd is OK. Reported 3 masters healthy:

```
cluster is healthy
member 2025245ceaafe339 is healthy
member b2e385dc8675fe92 is healthy
member fd304b55f10870a is healthy
```

When I tried to get node, I got an empty list, which may look bad...

```
oc get nodes
```

If I tried to login, I got the following:

```
oc get nodes
```

> Error from server: User "system" cannot list all nodes in the cluster

Is it a known issue? Where do you suggest me to check what is failing?

Comment: It looks like my issue is related to missing projects.
`oc get projects` return nothing.

Comment: But I can't create them. I tried `oc login system:admin -n default ; 
    oc new-project openshift --description="Openshift project"`
and it returns `Error from server: User "system:anonymous" cannot create subjectaccessreviews at the cluster scope`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not logged into openshift as system:admin.

To login as system:admin from the openshift machine:

oc config view

oc login -u system:admin

To check if you are logged in as system:admin, you can do oc whoami.

Comment: The issue is how to do it using Ansible